# MySQL, FULLTEXT in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, full-text-search

I've created a `FULLTEXT` index for the TEXT column `myColumn` my `MySQL` database in phpmyadmin.

1. The index for this column is reporting a cardinality of `50581`, exactly one third the number of rows in my table (i.e. 151743). Why is that? And does it matter? (I have also three TEXT columns, if that matters.)
2. I ask because my `MATCH` searches seem to be missing hits. For example, if I do `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MATCH(myColumn) AGAINST ('dude') ORDER BY id LIMIT 30` returns hits whereas `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MATCH(myColumn) AGAINST ('want') ORDER BY id LIMIT 30` returns none (when say `...LIKE '%want%'...` returns lots). Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure your table are MyISAM? Fulltext indices only work on MyISAM.

Comment: The table is definitely MyISAM. I've confirmed this in phpmyadmin (where I setup the database). But I have a partial FULLTEXT index on one column - its cardinality is exactly one third the number of rows. I have two other TEXT columns which I also need to have FULLTEXT index on - these are working fine and are fully indexed. Have you encountered this problem? Perhaps I need to adjust a limit some where?

Comment: I've never encountered something like this. Are the other two indices smaller then the one that doesn't work?

Comment: Their cardinalities are being reported (correctly?) as the number of rows in my table. That seems correct to me.